# How can i securely access a web based MYSQL database from an Android App

Tags: java, mysql, security

I have a SQL databse on the internet which has information
I need my Android app to be able to access that information
The app needs to know the username and password of the database
How can it know?

If i code it in, anyone can get it

Comment: A publicly accessible DB? That sounds like a disaster in the making. You should create a proper web service and let each user have their own username and password, with access only to their own data.

Comment: @thkla i need every copy of the app to access all data, but the data shouldnt be visible to user

Comment: That's impossible - if your application can access the data, then any sufficiently determined and knowledgeable user will be able to do the same.

Comment: You should have intermediatry to act as a go between the controls access to the databse, such as a web service for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Then the same problem applies to the web service as the DB

Comment: The web service is much easier to limit control frame external users. Direct access to the databse allows people to do what ever they want, where as a web service acts as a gate keeper. You could back the web service with some kind of application and data layer to further control the access. Each layer could have its own security model. This means the user/password needed to access the web service is different from the one used to access the application layer/database...

Comment: Like @thkala said: `There is no way to protect the DB credentials or the data from a sufficiently determined and knowledgeable user. If your application can access something, so can they.` The issue is you have to embed the credentials or a way to get the credentials in the app -> Huge security issue. Simply put: Do not do this. Just create a web service which you pass data to and it does what it needs to do then returns the data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, databases should not be publicly accessible, nor should they be directly accessed by a user application, for several very good reasons:

- There is generally no easy way to implement row-level access control. Views and triggers can only get you so far - in general application-level users do not map well to database users, since the latter usually have access to far more data than the former should have.
- The DB clients are tied to the actual database schema. Having clients not under your control like, say, an *Android application* is a very good way to tie yourself up in ways that would disallow any and all future development.
- Having a DB port open to the world is not considered by any means secure. Any potential security hole would give straight access to all of your data. The [MySQL security guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html) explicitly warn against opening the DB port to the internet.
- There is no way to protect the DB credentials or the data from a sufficiently determined and knowledgeable user. If your application can access something, so can they.
- Database access protocols are mostly designed with local-area networks in mind, rather than the inherently unreliable nature of the Internet. Even encryption and security are often more of an afterthought...

The standard way to approach this issue is to create an intermediate web service with separate user accounts and a restricted set of operations on the data. The web service would  let each user access only the data that relate to them, and even that indirectly. This approach separates the data from the user application layer, allows you the flexibility of storing and accessing your data however you wish and provides an additional layer of security for your DB.